# How can create a Data Tier Application in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, data-tier-applications

I read an article that talked about how to create a `Data Tier Applications` in `Visual Studio 2010`, this is the [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2100/introduction-to-data-tier-applications-in-sql-server-2008-r2/)

but i can not create this project in `VS 2013`, how can i do it?

NOTE: my `Visual studio` is `Ultimate`

Comment: I would recommend that you look into what an N-Tier application actually is... it is not a project type.

Comment: If you refer to my link, it shows a project named : SQl Server Data-tier application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now unified in Sql Server Database Project. And then on publish window you can select 'Register as a Data-tiea Application'

[image: Sql Server Database Project]

[image: SQL Database project publish]